# How to unwrap types from an array of classes in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that receives an array or rest of Typescript classes and will resolve and return its instances.

But, I am not able to have it correctly typed.

If I extract one:

```
class Base {
  isBase = true;
}
class Foo extends Base {
  isFoo = true;
}
class Bar extends Base {
  isBar = true;
}

export interface BaseType<Se extends Base = Base> {
  new (...args: any[]): Se;
}

function unwrap<T extends Base>(baseType: BaseType<T>): T {
  return new baseType();
}

unwrap(Foo).isFoo;
```

It works and it is correctly typed, returning the right type. But, if I have an array of them, it does not work:

```
function unwrapAll<T extends Base>(...baseType: BaseType<T>[]): T[] {
  return baseType.map(b => new b());
}

const [foo, bar] = unwrapAll(Foo, Bar);
console.log(foo.isFoo, bar.isBar);
```

I know Typescript had some news about [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html), but I still could not find a way to do it!

I found a way to manage it by using overloads but its limited

```
function unwrapAll<T0 extends Base>(bT0: BaseType<T0>): [T0];
function unwrapAll<T0 extends Base, T1 extends Base>(bT0: BaseType<T0>, bT1: BaseType<T1>): [T0, T1];
function unwrapAll<T0 extends Base, T1 extends Base, T2 extends Base>(
  bT0: BaseType<T0>,
  bT1: BaseType<T1>,
  bT2: BaseType<T2>
): [T0, T1, T2];
function unwrapAll<T0 extends Base, T1 extends Base, T2 extends Base, T3 extends Base>(
  bT0: BaseType<T0>,
  bT1: BaseType<T1>,
  bT2: BaseType<T2>,
  bT3: BaseType<T3>
): [T0, T1, T2, T3];
function unwrapAll<T extends Base>(...baseType: BaseType<T>[]): T[] {
  return baseType.map(b => new b());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is recently possible in 3.1 using [mapped tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063)

```
class Base {
  isBase = true;
}
class Foo extends Base {
  isFoo = true;
}
class Bar extends Base {
  isBar = true;
}

export interface BaseType<Se extends Base = Base> {
  new (...args: any[]): Se;
}


type UnwrapAll<T extends Array<BaseType<Base>>> ={ [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends BaseType<infer U> ? U : never}
function unwrapAll<T extends Array<BaseType<Base>>>(...baseType: T): UnwrapAll<T> {
  return baseType.map(b => new b()) as any;
}

const [foo, bar] = unwrapAll(Foo, Bar);
console.log(foo.isFoo, bar.isBar);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works pretty good.
This advanced TypeScript types are crazy!!

Comment: @Porfírio crazy fun :-)